# Python openpyxl error - I/O operation on closed file & memory error

Tags: python, pycharm, openpyxl

I created a code that takes a lot of data and organizes it in excel file using openpyxl.
recently, when dealing with big files, the system throws two errors:

```
...
File "C:\Users\...\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 931, in _serialize_xml
    write(" %s=\"%s\"" % (qnames[k], v))
MemoryError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

this happened right after generating 9 excel sheets, and trying to save them:

```
wb = Workbook()  
...
ws1 = wb.active
...
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("Timetable")
...
ws9 = wb.create_sheet("Statistics")
...  
wb.save(filepath + "\\" +filename)
del wb
gc.collect()
return True
```

I already tried to re-install openpyxl (now using version 3.0.9), enlarged the pycharm's RAM, freed a lot of memory using garbage collector. doesn't seems to help...

Comment: I may be stating the obvious when I say, run the code with smaller amounts of data and see at what file size you get the issue. You already identified that it may be a limit on memory usage.

Comment: Seeing as you're creating the workbook from scratch, you can always use write-only mode.